# Which Episode of Bleach is this quote from? / Help me cite this quote

Tags: bleach

I'm writing my dissertation and in the dedication I wanted to include this quote from the anime.

```
I wish I could have five lives!
Then I could have been born in five different towns,
and eaten five lifetime’s worth of food,
and had five different careers,
and... fallen in love with the same person, five times."
~ Inoue Orihime
```

However, in order to cite it correctly I believe I need to know the title of the episode and the date it aired. I can't seem to find this information anywhere, but I do know which book in the manga it comes from, Bleach manga; Chapter 237, pages 17-18. However I don't like that translation as much so I would prefer to cite the anime.

Bonus points will be awarded for providing the full citation as I'm a little shaky on that as well.

Edit: Thanks W. Are! You were spot on.
https://bleach.fandom.com/wiki/Goodbye...,_Kurosaki-kun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that it is indeed on **Chapter 237**, then the episode you are looking for is **Episode 141** titled *Goodbye..., Kurosaki!* which originally aired on September 19, 2007 while the English version aired later on August 15, 2009.

For future reference, the Bleach [wikia](https://bleach.fandom.com/wiki/Chapters), and most of the anime wikia, usually includes the chapter and the corresponding episode based on it while the [Wikipedia pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bleach_episodes#Season_7:_The_Arrancar_Part_2:_The_Hueco_Mundo_Sneak_Entry_(2007)) of anime usually includes the list of episodes together with their air dates.